# Is a 45% Active installs on android market place "high/low/don't know" for application?

Tags: android

What is an average "active installs" for an application listed on the Android Market place?

Answer (score 7):

It will probably depend on if you app is free or paid.  Im sure this [Android Market thread](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android%20Market/thread?tid=3f21d1b31b9015d8&hl=en) will help on determining what the 'average' is.

> Here is an estimate from data collected from a few friendly developers.
>
> The best or essential 
>    - ~ dozen free apps, have a retention ratio above 75%
>    - ~ 100 free apps, have a retention ratio above 50%
>
> Rest stay below 50% after the first month and average at around ~30%.
>
> Paid apps work in a different way for obvious reasons.

Comment: Paid apps probably are higher because if a person buys it; even if it doesn't work, they would still keep it.  Thanks for the info,

Comment: Not sure if you're aware or not but if you purchase an app and are dissatisfied, you can get a complete refund if you uninstall within 15 minutes of purchasing.

Answer (score 1):

There is no exact answer, since it depends from app to app. For example, there might be a utility that you just use and uninstall, or something like an alternate messaging application that you never uninstall. However, for an average application, 45% is slightly on the lower end. Get it to 60% and you're fine.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  My Active install % has been rising from a low of 28% to now a high of 45%. (42k total downloads)  I had a version that wasn't working right and resulted in a bunch of uninstalls.  Its a call log / call location app that the user would use daily.

Comment: I've never created an application which is used this frequently so can't really tell. However, this percentage is not exceptionally low so you shouldn't really be worried.

Answer (score 0):

At least in September 2010, Google admitted to there being a bug related to how active installs is counted:

"So far, this appears to be purely a reporting issue: some update events are being inaccurately recorded as uninstalls, rather than updates, creating a lower active installs percentage"

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android%20Market/thread?tid=2ad7b50d916b941b&hl=en

Don't know if this has been fixed yet.

Answer (score 0):

I published a free app about a month ago and I have a steady 98% active installs. :)

Comment: Congratulations for being the average developer with his average app

Comment: When an app is brand new, almost all installs are active. If you can keep active users for a long period of time, that's good. Everyone one churns eventually when they upgrade their device (even if they download again, you end up with an inactive install)