# Android Market Statistic

Tags: android, google-play

Sometimes statistics Android Market makes me wonder. When app have total installs ~10000-12000 it have only 45-55% active installs. What a ratio of quantities? In most cases, the application has good reviews (4.5 stars). Why active installs are only ~50%?
Look for example one of my app statistics:

Total: 12777
Active: 6158 (48%)

What you can say about this problem?
What statistics you have, what ratio between Total and Active installs you have?

Comment: Why do you think it's a problem? Users uninstall programs when they don't need them anymore.

Comment: Every day? First publish day have uninstalls too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

254 total, 58 active (22%). It's a work in progress, but the basic functionality is sound. At the end of the day, I'd be more concerned if the active installs go down over time or you get lots of bad reviews.

> What can you say about this problem?

What can I say? You're never going to please everybody, and with free apps/refunds on paid apps, you will get lots of people testing the water, deciding they don't like your app for whatever reason, and uninstalling it.

I know it doesn't do much for your ego - look at my stats for example - but that's life. You've had 12,777 people gice your app a try, and 6,158 keep it on their device. I think it's wrong to look at that as 6,619 people didn't like my app when you should be thinking of it as 6,158 people like my app enough to keep it installed. Or at the very least, 6,158 don't hate it enough to remove it.

The fact is, you have thousands of people using your app. Unfortunately there's no way to get feedback on why people remove it. What do the Market comments say? Do you notice a pattern of neutral/negative comments?

You could possibly try using something like Google Analytics in an attempt to notice a usage pattern to try to work out if there's something that people don't like.

Whatever you do, there's going to be a lot of guesswork involved and there's no easy answer.

Having said all that, I think 48% active installs is actually probably pretty good. The consensus in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637513/is-a-45-active-installs-on-android-market-place-high-low-dont-know-for-applic) thread suggests that the top dozen apps have active install ratios of about 75% or more, while the top 100 free apps have a retention ratio of around 50% or more. Everything else hovers around 50% for a month or so and then drops to around 30%.

Of course, that thread also mentions a bug in the reporting of active installs from September 2010, but there's no word on whether it's fixed or not. Either way, it looks like your app is actually doing quite well compared to others - I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Answer (score 0):

8250 total
4995 active installs (60 %)

I guess the percentage goes down while people download app. At first it was like 80-90%